# How does python handle module imports when module is installed on server?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When we do pip install CustomModule on PC (say server that hosts multiple python projects), and suppose the module is used in different python projects (via import ModuleName). Then Is the same module (and module variables) shared among all projects? Or are they shared in one project only?

By sharing I mean - if one project changes value of the module variable, will other project see the change?

What is the concept involved here?

Comment: The module is shared among all projects which use the same interpreter.

Comment: The *module*, as in the installed files, are shared. The values created at runtime are not shared, not even between two processes of the same project.

Comment: By sharing I mean - if one project changes value of the module variable, will other project see the change?

Comment: Importing a module is essentially running the module itself or the `__init__.py` file. Other projects will only see changes if you modify the source code of the module itself.